# Using ExecutorService and ProgressMonitor in a Thread Safe Manner

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, progressmonitor

I first define the ProgressMonitor:

```
progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(parent, "Starting processing ...", "", 0, maxNumberProcesses+1);
progressMonitor.setProgress(0);
```

and on the same thread use an ExecutorService and invokeAll() to process a list of Callables:

```
ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()); // use all available processors at startup
execService.invokeAll(callables); // wait for all tasks to complete
execService.shutdownNow(); // free thread pool resources
```

Each Callable is of the form:

```
class Callable implements Callable<List<String>>
{
    public List<String> call()
    {
        List<String> files = doSomeStuff();
        progressBarUpdate();
        return files;
    }
}
```

ie; each Callable calls progressBarUpdate():

```
private void progressBarUpdate()
{
    if (progressMonitor != null)
    {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        lock.lock();
        try
        {
            progressMonitor.increment();
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock(); // release lock
        }
    }
}
```

Each doSomeStuff() has its own exception handling and if an error occurs or an exception is thrown then a null value is returned. This is why the return type is a List, and returns null in such cases. There is no crossover between the Callables and the List of files they return, they all maintain there own list of files.

I find that it works fine but occasionally it throws an InterruptedException of the form:

```
Disposal was interrupted:
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1263)
at java.awt.Window.doDispose(Window.java:1209)
at java.awt.Dialog.doDispose(Dialog.java:1196)
at java.awt.Window.dispose(Window.java:1147)
at javax.swing.ProgressMonitor.close(ProgressMonitor.java:311)
at javax.swing.ProgressMonitor.setProgress(ProgressMonitor.java:264)
```

showing that setProgress() calls close() when the monitor max is reached:

```
public void setProgress(int nv) {
    if (nv >= max) {
        close();
    }
...
```

and close() contains numerous other non-thread safe calls.

I've modified my code so that the condition nv>=max is not satisfied and I explicitly call ProgressMonitor.close() after invokeAll(), but I'm still not convinced that such an approach is completely thread safe.

Has anyone else encountered this situation and found a rock-solid solution?

Thanks

Graham

PS. Note that ProgressMonitor is not a swing widget but does encapsulate Swing components. As a result I ensure that ProgressMonitor does not run on the EDT.

Comment: Which class is progressBarUpdate() part of? And, how does it receive progressMonitor?

Comment: It's a member of the same class with the ExecutorService and Callables list. The ProgressMonitor is a field since it is called by all Callables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a background task and show progress you should use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). The `SwingWorker` has a `progress` property that you can listen on. It ensures that the progress update is done in the *Event Dispatch Thread* while the task is done in a background thread.

For example:

```
SwingWorker<?,?> task = ...;
final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);

task.addPropertyChangeListener(
        new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public  void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                 if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                     progressBar.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
            }
        }
 });
```

The complete example code is in the javadoc of [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Comment: I'm using a collection of Callables with an ExecutorService that do not run on the EDT. The Swing ProgressMonitor is similarly a non-Swing component.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what is causing `interrupt`:

```
Worker Thread (Callable1):
close() -> doDispose() -> EventQueue.invokeAndWait() {
synchronized (lock) {
            Toolkit.getEventQueue().postEvent(event);
            lock.wait(); // --> (2) blocked window disposal event gets interrupted
        }
}

ExecutorService.shutdownNow() :
 try {
                for (Worker w : workers) {
                    w.interruptNow(); // (1) --> Setting interrupt flag
                }
            } catch (SecurityException se) { // Try to back out
                runState = state;
                // tryTerminate() here would be a no-op
                throw se;
            }
```

Functionally looks like, when your progress-monitor completes (or reached `max`), before the event is dispatched (may or may not occur depends how busy the eventQ is), service shutdown itself.

Conceptually I don't see any specific issue within your code, but its mainly implicit thread-communication by your executor-service to `AWT.EventQueue`.

You can either consume `InterruptedException` around `progressMonitor.increment();` or use `ExecutorService.awaitTermination` before calling `shutdownNow`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I call invokeAll(), which waits for all tasks to complete and presumably doesn't require a call to awaitTermination().

Comment: True, I missed `invokeAll` call But this can again call interrupt `future.cancel` incase of any error, and return. How are you handling errors inside `Callable.call` method, can you update your question?